# How do I pass a variable from one actionbean to another?

Tags: parameter-passing, stripes

Currently, I have a Stripes form with a submit button that's binded to the "search" method of the following ActionBean:

```
public class SearchRepairActionBean extends BaseActionBean {
  private String searchType;
  private String searchValue;

  @DefaultHandler   
  public Resolution defaultHandler(){
    return null;
  }

  @HandlesEvent("search")
  public Resolution search(){   
    return new ForwardResolution("SearchRepairResult.action").addParameter("searchType", searchType).addParameter("searchValue", searchValue);;
  }

  public String getSearchType() {
    return searchType;
  }

  public void setSearchType(String searchType) {
    this.searchType = searchType;
  }

  public String getSearchValue() {
    return searchValue;
  }

  public void setSearchValue(String searchValue) {
    this.searchValue = searchValue;
  }
}
```

And SearchRepairResultActionBean attempts to resolve it thus:

```
public class SearchRepairResultActionBean extends BaseActionBean {
private String searchType;
private String searchValue;

@DefaultHandler 
public Resolution defaultHandler(){
    return new ForwardResolution("/jsp/searchRepairResult.jsp");
}

@HandlesEvent("SearchRepairResult")
public Resolution SearchRepairResult(){
    System.out.println(searchType);
    System.out.println(searchValue);    
    }
public String getSearchType() {
    return searchType;
}

public void setSearchType(String searchType) {
    this.searchType = searchType;
}

public String getSearchValue() {
    return searchValue;
}

public void setSearchValue(String searchValue) {
    this.searchValue = searchValue;
}
}
```

The problem is when I try to print "searchType" and "searchValue" - they return null. Am I passing parameters incorrectly? What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you getting the `type` and `value` by calling `getContext().getRequest().getParameter()`?  You should be able to just have methods on your `SearchRepairResultActionBean` like so:

```
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

And then Stripes will inject the necessary values in (as part of `LifecycleStage.BindingAndValidation`) before calling your event method.

Actually, for that matter, why are you separating `SearchRepairActionBean` from `SearchRepairResultActionBean`?  If the "result" page needs to view the data that came from the form that was submitted to the `search` event, then why not just perform the action in the `search()` method on `SearchRepairActionBean`, and then do a `ForwardResolution` on to your view?  Is there a particular reason for using two ActionBeans here?

Comment: Sorry, the forwardresolution is supposed to go to another jsp - edited my question to reflect that

Comment: @echoblaze: Well, then if the forward resolution is going to a JSP, why do you expect a second ActionBean will be executed?

Comment: good point; I'll need to forward to the SearchRepairActionBean after all and ForwardResolution to searchRepairResult.jsp from there. I'm still getting nulls, but I'll update my question to reflect these changes

Comment: @echoblaze: OK, now you're halfway there.  You're forwarding onto the second ActionBean, but you're not attaching the parameters (with `.addParameter()`) when you forward.  Do both, and you should get the expected result.

Comment: thanks so much ! The parameters now print correctly. I'm wondering why I cannot access those variables' values in my other method inside the same ActionBean (this other method is named in a .js file as a DataTables Ajax source), but that's beyond the scope of this question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can pass a parameter.

There are several other possibilities, but that is probably your best case without seeing your exact code.  You might have missed it, as it is actually a method of the superclass (OnwardResolution).

It's chainable, so you can call it multiple times in a row if necessary.

```
return new ForwardResolution(BarActionBean.class,"barevent").addParameter("ducks",ducks);
```

Javadoc: [public T addParameters(Map parameters)](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/OnwardResolution.html#addParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working =( i'm editing my question to clarify my problem